# Realtime database rules - Check if a given array includes newData.val()

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a property in my RTDB that can be only one of: `false, 5, 15, 30, 60`.

So I tried to write this condition in multiple ways without any success:

```
// Like in Firestore rules:
".write": "newData().val() in [false, 5, 15, 30, 60]"

// Like in ES6:
".write": "[false, 5, 15, 30, 60].includes(newData().val())"

// Like the old way:
".write": "[false, 5, 15, 30, 60].indexOf(newData().val()) > -1"
```

So I eventually ended up with:

```
".write": "(newData.val() === false || newData.val() === 5 || newData.val() === 15 || newData.val() === 30 || newData.val() === 60"
```

Is there any way I can check if `newData.val()` equals to one of the mentioned values without too much boilerplate?

Comment: The rule you ended up with is how I'd write it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to compact this would be to use a regular expression. So according to your example, you could utilize `".write": "(newData.val()+'').matches(/^(false|5|15|30|60)$/)"`.

However, you probably want to be a bit more strict on data types, so something like this would be ideal: `".write": "newData.val() === false || (newData.isNumber() && (newData.val()+'').matches(/^(5|15|30|60)$/))"`

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/m5gzt423/